# DONOT show JaCoCo report on SONAR

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco

I downloaded a maven project from this link
Project samples are available on github that can be browsed or downloaded: projects/languages/java/code-coverage/ut

When I run "mvn clean test sonar:sonar" from the command line, I see the jacoco.exe file getting generated and shows the report in SONAR. What can I do to NOT show this code coverage report on the SONAR?

Can you please tell me the settings that I need to make?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your SonarQube version but I guess launching the same command with "-Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=false" should do the job.